# Python ast code transform keep comments

Tags: python, refactoring, abstract-syntax-tree

I am doing code transforms on old python code using the `ast` module. But when I write the newly converted code it does not include comments. I know that the ast just ignores comments because they are not important in regards to the code. But I would like to keep the comments in the code after the transform. How would I do this?

Comment: Please provide the code you are using now.